# "Who invited you to the UK?" on visa application to attend academic conference

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, conferences

For a student attending an academic conference, [these guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) specify that a standard visitor visa for business must be applied for.

However, the visa application includes a question "Who invited you to the UK?" and requires that the applicant enter the full name of an individual.

The academic conference does not issue letters of invitation, and only issues support letters for visa applications.

In such a scenario, how must this field be filled? It is marked as mandatory.

Comment: If you are presenting, then use whoever sent you the acceptance letter, or just the conference chairman? If you have a support letter, then maybe it has a name on it?

Comment: @TomasBy Thank you, that is an option, but is that the correct/acceptable thing to do?

Comment: If it feels so important then you probably have to contact them and ask. I don't think it is important, if it is clear you are going to a conference. It will not be the first time somebody applies for a visa for that purpose.

Comment: The problem: there are many people who check conferences just to get invitation and visa (and then never show up to conference). This causes some troubles to organizers, so they usually do no invite people (but speakers). Note: not all business people get invited, so just leave the field clear. If you have a good visa application, the officer will see quickly that your are an academic person and he will check the documentation as such.

Comment: Where on the [Standard Visitor visa application form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589170/VAF1-visitandshorttermstay.pdf) are you finding that question?

Comment: VTC: OP has not further clarified, as asked, making it difficult to respond (or understand whether the correct form is being used).